# Replacing <ul> with For-loops, and failing miserably

Tags: python, html, bottle

I'm trying to crate a webpage and decided to make a For-loop instead of using ul. I am using bottle and can't figure out why this code doesn't work.

```
<%
titles = ["Home", "Tutorial", "Contact", "Upload"]
links = ["/", "/tutorial", "/contact", "/tool"]
clas = ["navbar__links", "navbar__links", "navbar__links", "button"]
kat = ["navbar__item", "navbar__item", "navbar__item", "navbar__btn"]
%>
% for i in range(len(titles)):
    print(f"<ul class="navbar__menu"><li class="{kat[i]}"><a href="{links[i]}" class="{clas[i]}">{titles[i]}</a></li></ul>");
% end
```

The code should replace this html:

```
<ul class="navbar__menu">
    <li class="navbar__item">
        <a href="/" class="navbar__links">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li class="navbar__item">
        <a href="/tutorial" class="navbar__links">Tutorial</a>
    </li>
    <li class="navbar__item">
        <a href="/contact" class="navbar__links">Contact</a>
    </li>
    <li class="navbar__btn">
        <a href="/tool" class="button">Upload</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! When you say that your code "doesn't work," can you be more specific? What happens? Is there a stack trace (from the logs) that you can provide? That would help us help you.

Comment: The direct HTML is much clearer IMO. Why do you feel the need to make this refactor? I'd only use a loop when you have tons of dynamic data, like a list of posts or users pulled from a database.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're confusing Python's f-string literals and Bottle templates. Bottle already treats the contents of the `for` loop as a string. Use double braces `{{ }}` to interpolate expressions.

Secondly, you don't want each item to be in a list of one element. Wrap the `<ul>` around the whole loop so that you have one list with 4 items.

```py
<%
titles = ["Home", "Tutorial", "Contact", "Upload"]
links = ["/", "/tutorial", "/contact", "/tool"]
clas = ["navbar__links", "navbar__links", "navbar__links", "button"]
kat = ["navbar__item", "navbar__item", "navbar__item", "navbar__btn"]
%>
<ul class="navbar__menu">
% for i in range(len(titles)):
  <li class="{{kat[i]}}">
    <a href="{{links[i]}}" class="{{clas[i]}}">
      {{titles[i]}}
    </a>
  </li>
% end
</ul>
```

But I'd suggest taking a step back and thinking about whether this is an improvement. I'd argue it's much less readable than the original version. I'd only use a loop when I have dynamic data, like a list of posts or users pulled from a database.

If I had to do this sort of thing, I'd define the data structure differently. 4 loose lists in separate variables is ripe for bugs; it's easy for one list to grow an extra element and wind up with a weird situation. The `i` has little semantic value and can also result in bugs. I'm also unsure of what `kat` is, and intentional misspellings like `clas` are painful to see.

It makes more sense to use a list as the outermost data structure, with a dict to represent each list item:

```py
<%
list_items = [
    dict(title="Home", url="/", li_class="navbar__urls", a_class="navbar__item"),
    dict(title="Tutorial", url="/tutorial", li_class="navbar__urls", a_class="navbar__item"),
    dict(title="Contact", url="/contact", li_class="navbar__urls", a_class="navbar__item"),
    dict(title="Upload", url="/tool", li_class="button", a_class="navbar__btn"),
]
%>
<ul class="navbar__menu">
% for li in list_items:
  <li class="{{li["li_class"]}}">
    <a href="{{li["url"]}}" class="{{li["a_class"]}}">
      {{li["title"]}}
    </a>
  </li>
% end
</ul>
```

This "unpivoted" structure keeps each list item's data together and maps much more nicely to the output list. I still very much question whether it's necessary; this is more of an "if you have to do this, then..." suggestion.

Another thought is that you have a lot of duplicate data here, so you can clip out the last list item, hardcode that, and keep the top 3 dynamic:

```py
<%
list_items = [
    dict(title="Home", url="/"),
    dict(title="Tutorial", url="/tutorial"),
    dict(title="Contact", url="/contact"),
]
%>
<ul class="navbar__menu">
% for li in list_items:
  <li class="navbar__urls">
    <a href="{{li["url"]}}" class="navbar__item">
      {{li["title"]}}
    </a>
  </li>
% end
  <li class="button">
    <a href="/tool" class="navbar__btn">Upload</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

This still feels premature and overengineered, but can't hurt to toss out alternatives for educational purposes.